# React mui dialog body padding with custom scrollbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dialog

I have a React `mui` theme with a custom scrollbar like this:

```
ui.material.createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: {
        '::-webkit-scrollbar': {
          width: '100px'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then I use a *Dialog*. This adds `padding-right` and `overflow` to the body:

[image]

At this point `padding-right: 19px` is incorrect. It should be `100px`. What is the appropriate location to override these styles in mui? I'm aware I can add a CSS override for this situation but I'd like to solve in the proper, supported way, that mui probably provides somehow.